# cannot concatenate 'str' and 'type' objects (beginner)

Tags: python, class

I've been given a class to inherit functions from.

```
class shape(object):
    '''Shape is an base class, which is largely intended to be abstract, that
    is only used as a parent class to other classes wich define specific shapes
    and inherit the shape class' fuctions getArea() and printArea()
    '''

    def __init__(self):
        '''constructor function for the shape class
        '''
        self.area = None
        self.name = "shape"

    def getArea(self):
        '''returns the area of the shape, which is defined in the constructor
        '''
        return self.area

    def printArea(self):
        '''prints a statement identifying the shape by its name and giving the
        area of the shape. Returns None.
        '''
        print "The area of this " + self.name + " is: " + str(self.area)
        return None
```

I have to work with that, so it can't change. Then, what I've done is:

```
class circle(shape):
    """A new class 'circle' that will inherit functions from the class 'shape'.
    """

    def __init__(self, diameter):
        """A constructor function for the circle class.
        """
        self.area = math.pi * (diameter ** 2 / 4.0)
        self.name = circle

c = circle(10)

print c.getArea()
print c.printArea()
```

The getArea part works fine, but the printArea doesn't. I get the error message that's in the title.

Comment: Look closely at the `self.name = ....` line in the `shape` class definition, comparing that to your own class `__init__` method. See anything different about those lines?

Comment: Ohh, I see! Thank you for your help :) I was getting a massive headache from this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self.name` needs to be `"circle"`, not `circle`.